# Select2 closes immediately after data loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

Im trying to load data to select2 with ajax post method on click. But after data loads the selectbox closes. I have to open it again to see data. I need it to be stay opened. Here my code.

```
$('#newLawyer').select2();
$('#newLawyer').one('select2:opening', function() {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: API_URL + 'getMemberList',
        async: true
    }).done(function (data) {
        console.log(data)
        result = $.map(data.data, function (obj) {
            return {
                text: obj.name,
                id: obj.id
            };
        });
        $("#newLawyer").select2({
            placeholder: "Bir seçim yapınız",
            data: result,
            cache: true
        });
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#newLawyer').select2({
  minimumInputLength : 0,
  ajax: {
    url: API_URL + 'getMemberList',
    method: 'POST',
    async: true,
    dataType: 'json'
    processResults: function (data) {
      // Transforms the top-level key of the response object from 'items' to 'results'
      const results = [];
      data.data.map(obj=> {
        if( /* any search condition put here */ ) {
          results.push({text: obj.name, id: obj.id})
        } 
      });

      return { results };
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm ! Thank you

Comment: But there is a problem. If i type anything to search, its spamming to post for every letter

Comment: This is the default behaviour for searching remotely...

Comment: if you want to post on minimum letter typing set `minimumInputLength: 1 or 2 or any number`

Comment: Well yes i can do it but its not searching in results. The matched word is not coming up.

Comment: because you are not passing any data for search

Comment: Cant i search in found results ?

Comment: I have updated answer `/* any search condition put here */` inside if condition you can put any filter you want

Comment: Well thanks for your support but i couldnt understand what should i check there. :/